# Redux rendering default state before initial state - server side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm not sure where i'm going wrong. But i'm trying out server side rendering in redux. when i load the page , i quickly get a glimpse of the default value provided to the reducer before it changes to the initial state supplied by the server

this is my server.js file

```
app.use(serveStatic(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use(cookieParser())
  app.use(passport.initialize())

app.get('/auth/github',passport.authenticate('github'))

  app.get('/auth/github/callback',passport.authenticate('github',{failureRedirect:'/fail'}),
    function(req,res){
      // var text = JSON.stringify({id_token: req.user.token})
      console.log('req.user.token',req.user.token)
      var text=  JSON.stringify(req.user.token)
      //expire in 10 years
      res.cookie('id_token',text,{ expires: new Date(Date.now() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 30 * 12 * 10)), httpOnly: true })
      res.redirect('/')
    }
  )

  app.use(handleRender)

  function handleRender(req,res){
    // const store = createStore(rootReducer)
    console.log('handleRender hit')
    console.log('req object',req)
    const html = renderToString(
      Route
    )
    initialState = {UserDetails : {username:'Mikael Akerfeldt'}}
    res.send(renderFullPage(html,initialState))
  }

  function renderFullPage(html,initialState){
    return `
      <!doctype html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Redux Universal</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="app"><div>${html}</div></div>
          <script>
            window.__INITIAL_STATE__= ${JSON.stringify(initialState)}
          </script>
          <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
        </body>
      </html>`
  }
```

my index.js file on the client side

```
const initialState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__

export const store = createStore(rootReducer,initialState)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/hello" component={hello} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  ,document.getElementById('app')
)
```

my app.js file

```
class App extends React.Component{

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('mounted')
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Hello </p>
          <a href="/auth/github">Sign up with github </a>
        <h1> {this.props.username} </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  const {username} = state.UserDetails
  return{
    username
  }
}

App = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

export default App
```

my reducer

```
const UserDetails = (state={username: 'anon'},action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'USER_TYPE':
      console.log('reducer hit')
      return Object.assign({},
        state,{username:action.username
        })
        default:
          return state
  }

}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  UserDetails
})
```

As you can see , i've set a default state of 'username' : anon in my reducer. the initial state for the reducer however is sent from the server  with the username 'mikael'

when i load the page , for a brief second the this.props.username is anon before it changes to 'mikael'. but my store is properly getting initialized with the initialState sent from the server. Why am i still seeing the default state?

Comment: How are you creating the `rootReducer`?

Comment: forgot to include that .. but its just combineReducers

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any dispatcher being called? I can't understand why is there a change of `this.props.username`. The reducers should only be called once for the inital state.

Comment: i dont dispatch any actions .. i just initialize the store with the initial state. Could it be a problem with the reducer returning the default case before initialState is rendered?

Comment: Well, it shouldn't happen (I'm not sure about how you use `combineReducers`) because `state` shouldn't be undefined there. It should be injecting an object in the reducer, so the default value of `state` should be ignored.

Comment: I've included the combineReducer line as well .. do i need to use it on the server side as well?

Comment: No, it's not needed. Have you checked the contents of `initialstate`? Log those values out or use a debugger.